# How to do select insert into statements and handling time series data and foreign keys?

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-insert

I am completely lost on how to approach the problem I am having.  I am trying to generate a boolean statement from one table and insert it into another table's column.  I am able to generate the boolean statement and create a new column as shown with the code and output below:

```
 SELECT date_price, stock_id, (adj_close_price>ub1_50_d) as d20_l_d50
 FROM bollinger_bands
 LIMIT 100;
```

[image: Boolean output]

This is what I have so far:

```
INSERT INTO decisions (stock_id,
                   date_price,  
                   created_date,
                   last_updated_date,
                   d20_l_d50)
 VALUES         
                   ( ,
                     ,
                   now(),
                   now(),
                   (SELECT adj_close_price > ub1_50_d as d20_l_d50
                   FROM bollinger_bands)
                   );
```

[image: Current decision table]

I am stuck on how to insert the boolean output into another table's column.  Two columns I am particularly unclear on are: the date column and the stock_id column.   I don't even know if I am on the right path at this point and what to look for.  Any assistance and suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: to insert data from one table to another look at the ```INSERT INTO table1(somecolumns) SELECT something FROM table2```, every column in select will go into its column in insert

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get rid of the `values` clause:

```
INSERT INTO decisions (stock_id,date_price,created_date, last_updated_date, d20_l_d50)
select date_price, stock_id, now(), now(), adj_close_price > ub1_50_d
FROM bollinger_bands;
```

Comment: Thank you that worked perfectly.  I guess I tried to make it more complicated than it should have been.

Answer (score 1):

The following syntax [creates a new table](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-selectinto.html) named `decisions` with the data you provided.

```
select  'Dummy', now(), now(), now(),
adj_close_price > ub1_50_d as d20_l_d50
INTO decisions 
from bollinger_bands
--limit 100 -- For testing?
```

If you already have a table with data in it, you're going to want to [update that table](https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-update-join/#:%7E:text=Sometimes%2C%20you%20need%20to%20update,new_value%20FROM%20t2%20WHERE%20t1.).

```
UPDATE decisions dcs
SET d20_l_d50 = adj_close_price>ub1_50_d
FROM bollinger_bands bbd
WHERE bbd.stock_id = dcs.stock_id
 -- and bbd.date_price = dcs.date_price?
```

Comment: That creates a new table, it doesn't insert into an existing table (the syntax is also discouraged in favor of the standard compliant `CREATE TABLE AS`)

Comment: You're right. I have updated my answer with a clarification.

Comment: Thank you for the update statement.  The table will need to be updated daily.